# Silverlight MultiscaleImage fill available height

Tags: silverlight, multiscaleimage

I have a sample app with a MultiScaleImageControl. By default it fills the available ViewPort width. How can i make it use the available height?

**Edit** (Copy from comment)

It's nothing more than

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <MultiScaleImage HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="multiScaleImage1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

My question doesn't aim at the width of the control itself, but at the displayed MultiScaleImage...

Comment: Can you share the XAML on the page?

Comment: It's nothing more than `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <MultiScaleImage HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="multiScaleImage1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>` My question doesn't aim at the width of the control itself, but at the displayed MultiScaleImage...

Comment: Please use the edit function on your question to when including additional information.  Mark and code especially do not work well in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you remove the `VerticalAlignment` property.  In fact get rid of the `HorizontalAlignment` as well.  This lets the containing grid size the control for you.

You may also be seeing the control simply maintaining the aspect ratio of the image.  If the image is wider than its high then at zoom level 1 the image will not fill the entire height.